# How to attach event on HTML elements which I have created using jquery on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var li = $("<li>").attr({
    id: "print",
    click: function(e){
     alert(this);
     console.log(this);
    }
 });
```

I have tried this code but it invokes sooner the code generates the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var li = $("<li>",{
    id: "print"            //the second parameter accepts properties as an object
}).on('click',function(e){ //.on() binds the event to that element
    console.log(this);
});
```

or alternatively:

```
var li = $("<li>",{
    id: "print"            //the second parameter accepts properties as an object
    click: function(e){    //attach the event as part of the properties
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: click events get fired when JS create the LI element.

Comment: @DeepakKaithwas I'm not using `.attr()` in the second code. I just passed it in the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var li = $('<li>').attr({
    id: "print"
}).click(function() {
    alert(this);
    consol.log(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event to a tag with .on()

An example:

```
$('li#print').on('click',function(e){
  alert("Something" + $(this));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'click' method.

```
var li = $("<li>").attr({
   id: "print"
}).click(function(e) {
   alert(this);
   console.log(this);
});
```

Or if you want to attach event to dynamic generated elements, use `$.live` function.
If you use jQuery mobile, i must say another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can make use of event-bubbling and attach a delegated event listener to a parent node. Doing so, you can attach the event-listener before you actually add the element to the DOM.

Or you could attach the element to the DOM before you try to attach the event listener:

```
$("<li>")
    .attr({ id: "print"})
    .appendTo("body") // Or wherever you want to put it
    .on("click", function(e){
       alert(this);
       console.log(this);
    });
```